# Getting info about unhandled C++ exception

Tags: c++, exception

Some C++ programs may not handle all of the exceptions. If it is main thread of course it is easy to create `try {} catch` in `main()`. But programs may have hundreds of different threads. And it is not that easy to handle exceptions in all the threads.

Each unhandled exception terminates program immediately. I expect that it terminates it through calling [std::terminate()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate).

My question is whether it is possible anyhow to get some information about unhandled exceptions before program dies?

For example I can set my callback through [std::set_terminate()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/set_terminate). Also I can print stack to console through [Boost.StackTrace](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/stacktrace.html).

But besides stack trace is it possible anyhow to get some information about thrown exception? For example there exist [std::exception_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception_ptr), which can carry any exception information. So maybe all unhandled exceptions are registered somewhere by system through some imaginary function like `std::set_unhandled_exception_ptr(exc);`.

What information and how can I get about unhandled exception?

Also if not possible to get information, at least maybe there is any way how to catch all exceptions in all threads? Some imaginary `std::set_default_exc_handler(...);`.

Comment: Note that if you are on Windows there is also the possibility of [SEH exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43805788/get-meaningful-information-from-seh-exception-via-catch) which are their own headache to deal with

Comment: No, there's no standard way of doing that (by the time you hit the terminate handler, the stack might have been unwound, and there's no guarantee that terminate is called on the same thread that threw the exception). Yes, wrapping all your threads in `try {} catch{}` is the simplest way to do that.

Comment: @CoryKramer If possible I need cross-platform code that works on Win/Lin/Mac.

Comment: @YakovGalka As I remember Visual Studio always when program crashes says something `Terminating because of unhandled exception std::runtime_error`, and maybe even showed message of this exception like `bad allocation`. How Visual Studio achieved this by default? It should have added some default handler of unhandled exceptions.

Comment: @Arty MSVC attaches itself as a debugger. Debuggers get a 'first chance exception notification' before your process can do anything about it.

Comment: @YakovGalka This info about exception was shown not by a debugger but by regular non-debug run of a program compiled by MSVC. It showed info as popup Msg Box. Even if you close Visual Studio and run this program it shows a message. I don't remember, but probably only if you compile it in Debug mode.

Comment: I put my shoes on, but didn't put my socks on. Now I want to put on my socks; how can I do that without taking off my shoes? The way to handle exceptions is to handle them. If you did it wrong, you have to fix it.

Comment: @PeteBecker The problem is that I have ready-made program by others. It rarely crashes due to unhandled exceptions. All exceptions may happen in many threads. Those threads are created in many places of huge library, deep inside library. Wrapping all such threads into try/catch is not possible. My current task is just to be more informative when program crashes. For that I wanted to figure out if it is possible to show anything useful besides terminate message. I just tried right now to print a stack trace and it appeared that it shows UnWounded stack, doesn't show point of `throw`.

Comment: @Arty The [message box you're talking about](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yDTzZ.jpg) is shown by the debugger. If you're running your application without a debugger, it will show [the "Close the Program/Debug the Program/Send Report" dialog](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4O46m.jpg). If you click the "Debug the Program" it will let you open Visual Studio, which will attach itself and show the dialog with the "unhandled exception" information.

Comment: @YakovGalka Are you saying that when you click `Debug the Program` then MSVS attaches and shows correct information about exception? How does it now it, info? Without re-running the program from start.

Comment: @Arty The exception information is in there in your process memory. The Debugger can access it [through the appropriate API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-exception_debug_info). You can get that in-process through the [vectored exception handling](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-addvectoredexceptionhandler). However the mapping between SEH exceptions and C++ exception is, AFAIK, undocumented. So good luck reverse engineering that. And, did I say that, there's no standard way of doing that?